# I made Stopwatch using JS and it's not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JS and I tried to make a simple stopwatch with JS by watching some tutorials. In the tutorial, the code running perfectly, but when I tried it doesn't work. What could the problem be?

thanks in advance.‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎
‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎

```js
var seconds = 00;
var tens = 00;
var appendTens = document.getElementById("tens");
var appendSeconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
var buttonStart = document.getElementById("button-start");
var buttonStop = document.getElementById("button-stop");
var buttonReset = document.getElementById("button-reset");
var interval;

function startTimer() {
    tens++;

    if (tens < 9) {
        appendTens.innerHTML = "0" + tens;
    }
    if (tens > 9) {
        appendTens.innerHTML = tens;
    }
    if (tens > 99) {
        seconds++;
        appendSeconds.innerHTML = "0" + seconds;
        tens = 0;
        appendTens.innerHTML = "0" + 0;
    }
    if (seconds > 9) {
        appendSeconds.innerHTML = seconds;
    }
}

buttonStart.onclick = function() {
    interval = setInterval(startTimer, 10);
};

buttonStop.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
};

buttonReset.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    tens = "00";
    seconds = "00";
    appendSeconds.innerHTML = seconds;
    appendTens.innerHTML = tens;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>StopWatch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
    
        <p><span id="seconds ">00</span>: <span id="tens ">00</span></p>
        <button id="button-start">Start</button>
        <button id="button-stop">Stop</button>
        <button id="button-reset">Reset</button>


        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Edit: the problem is I add space at the ID.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: Maybe remove the trailing space after `id="tens "`?

Comment: The error "can't access innerHTML property of null" is telling you what the problem is. You failed to pick up the element which, as @Someone_who_likes_SE points out, is down to the space in the id name.

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE Yes, the space was the problem. Thank you, it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove **extra space** from `id="seconds "` and `id="tens "`
It should be `id="seconds"` and `id="tens"`
Now it's works fine ;-)

```js
var seconds = 00;
var tens = 00;
var appendTens = document.getElementById("tens");
var appendSeconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
var buttonStart = document.getElementById("button-start");
var buttonStop = document.getElementById("button-stop");
var buttonReset = document.getElementById("button-reset");
var interval;

function startTimer() {
    tens++;

    if (tens < 9) {
        appendTens.innerHTML = "0" + tens;
    }
    if (tens > 9) {
        appendTens.innerHTML = tens;
    }
    if (tens > 99) {
        seconds++;
        appendSeconds.innerHTML = "0" + seconds;
        tens = 0;
        appendTens.innerHTML = "0" + 0;
    }
    if (seconds > 9) {
        appendSeconds.innerHTML = seconds;
    }
}

buttonStart.onclick = function() {
    interval = setInterval(startTimer, 10);
};

buttonStop.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
};

buttonReset.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    tens = "00";
    seconds = "00";
    appendSeconds.innerHTML = seconds;
    appendTens.innerHTML = tens;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>StopWatch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
    
        <p><span id="seconds">00</span>: <span id="tens">00</span></p>
        <button id="button-start">Start</button>
        <button id="button-stop">Stop</button>
        <button id="button-reset">Reset</button>


        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```